# rspec: Stub a template's helper method call from a controller spec using render_views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, stub

From Rails 3 / Rspec 2, I'm attempting to leverage the [render_views](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/dir/controller-specs/render-views) feature of controller specs.  The issue I've come across is that we've just installed the [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) pager gem, and I want to stub out the `<%= paginate @sites %>` call from my view so I don't have to manually stub out all the internal methods that kaminari defines on the collection for use with `paginate` helper.

If this was in a view spec, I could stub out the helper method by calling `view.stub(:paginate)`, but I can't find any way to get a handle on the view object from a controller spec (e.g. `controller.view.stub(:paginate)`).  Is there any way to do this, or are our options to either disable render_views for this method, or to stub a bunch of internal kaminari methods that aren't relevant to us (since they should be covered by kaminari's tests, and might change in future versions)?

```
describe SitesController do
  render_views

  def mock_site(stubs={})
    @mock_site ||= mock_model(Site, stubs).as_null_object
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all sites as @sites" do
      Site.stub_chain("enabled.ordered.page") {[mock_site]}
      # want to do something here like: controller.view.stub(:paginate)
      get :index
      assigns(:sites).should eq([mock_site])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Either I couldn't find a proper solution.

Probably you may want to investigate `controller.view_context` a little bit more.

What I settled with (for now) is a monkey patch in rspec/support/kaminari.rb:

```
module Kaminari::ActionViewExtension::InstanceMethods
  def paginate(scope, options = {}, &block)
    puts "Should test pagination"
  end
end
```

So it silently fails pagination.